# addings tags outside the user's selection

Tags: jquery, selection

I am trying to create a very baic wysiwyg editor. I've search a lot and I didn't succee to find some think that works and answer what I need.
I found someone's code that should add  tags arround the selection but it doesn't work for me. Do you know the problem?
I need actually find out if there is some tags wrapping the text and if yes I will be able to change them, and if not, I will add some tags.

Thank you very much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>check</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("p").live("mouseup",function() {
selection = getSelectedText();
if(selection.length >= 3) {
    var spn = '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + selection +     '</span>';
    $(this).text($(this).html().replace(selection, spn));
}
});

//Grab selected text
function getSelectedText(){
if(window.getSelection){
    return window.getSelection().toString();
}
else if(document.getSelection){
    return document.getSelection();
}
else if(document.selection){
    return document.selection.createRange().text;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> check check check </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try out this basic demo, might you can use some of it: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/editor/midasdemo/

Comment: save yourself 500h of work and just download this! https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/downloads . A great jQuery WYSIWYG editor

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide that culd help you building your own wysiwyg editor. 
Might find something useful there:
Link [Crete your own wysiwyg editor](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/HTML/Building-a-WYSIWYG-HTML-Editor-Part-1/1/)